# make a variable default if something on sql server insert stament

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to insert the default values, if the values i gave him are 0 or ''

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[altaemp]
    @id_emp int,
    @nom_emp varchar(100),
    @lnom_emp varchar(100),
    @l2nom_emp varchar(100),
    @id_type int,
    @id_supervisor int,
    @correo varchar(50),
    @id_area int
    as
    begin

    if @id_supervisor = 0 (select @id_supervisor = ?? )
    if @correo = '' (select @correo = ??)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[empleados]
           ([id_emp]
           ,[nom_emp]
           ,[lnom_emp]
           ,[l2nom_emp]
           ,[id_type]
           ,[id_supervisor]
           ,[correo]
           ,[id_area])
     VALUES
           (@id_emp,
           @nom_emp,
           @lnom_emp,
           @l2nom_emp,
           @id_type,
           @id_supervisor,
           @correo,
           @id_area)
return 
end
```

i have tried equals the variables to null or default without success

Comment: `i want to insert the default values, if the values i gave it are 0 or ' '`. What are default values here?

Comment: Check the use of `CASE` construct. You can use it for each relevant **value** within the `INSERT` command.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can pass null instead of 0 and '', then you can set your default value with the parameter definition in which case you will not need to do any IF/CASE.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas the default value for id_supervisor is 842 and for correo is sin correo

Comment: @AhmedSaeed i cant pass null

Comment: @EdgarGerardoBorregoPeña, passing null example shown.

Answer (score 0):

To handle these 2 cases you can add the following decision statements, replacing ?? with your replacement value:

```
IF LEN(@correo) = 0 SET @correo = ??
IF @id_supervisor = 0 SET @id_supervisor = ??
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a `COALESCE` with a `NULLIF` inside it to achieve this.

```
 SELECT @id_supervisor = COALESCE(NULLIF(@id_supervisor,0),[DEFAULT VALUE])
           ,@correo = COALESCE(NULLIF(@correo ,' '),[DEFAULT VALUE])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for handling this scenario.  If they are truly default values, you can simply pass null into the stored procedure and define the procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[altaemp]
    @id_emp int,
    @nom_emp varchar(100),
    @lnom_emp varchar(100),
    @l2nom_emp varchar(100),
    @id_type int,
    @id_supervisor int = <default supervisor id>,
    @correo varchar(50) = <default correo>,
    @id_area int
    as
    begin

INSERT INTO [dbo].[empleados]
       ([id_emp]
       ,[nom_emp]
       ,[lnom_emp]
       ,[l2nom_emp]
       ,[id_type]
       ,[id_supervisor]
       ,[correo]
       ,[id_area])
 VALUES
       (@id_emp,
       @nom_emp,
       @lnom_emp,
       @l2nom_emp,
       @id_type,
       @id_supervisor,
       @correo,
       @id_area)
return 
end
```

Alternatively, if there is a decision that has to be made, you can replace your logic with case logic which would look similar to this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[altaemp]
    @id_emp int,
    @nom_emp varchar(100),
    @lnom_emp varchar(100),
    @l2nom_emp varchar(100),
    @id_type int,
    @id_supervisor int = <default supervisor id>,
    @correo varchar(50) = <default correo>,
    @id_area int
    as
    begin

INSERT INTO [dbo].[empleados]
       ([id_emp]
       ,[nom_emp]
       ,[lnom_emp]
       ,[l2nom_emp]
       ,[id_type]
       ,[id_supervisor]
       ,[correo]
       ,[id_area])
 Select @id_emp,
       @nom_emp,
       @lnom_emp,
       @l2nom_emp,
       @id_type,
       CASE WHEN @id_supervisor = 0 THEN <Default SupervisorId> ELSE @id_supervisor END,
       CASE WHEN @correo= '' THEN <Default correo> ELSE @correo  END,
       @id_area
return 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can pass null instead of 0 and '', then you can try this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[altaemp]
    @id_emp int,
    @nom_emp varchar(100),
    @lnom_emp varchar(100),
    @l2nom_emp varchar(100),
    @id_type int,
    @id_supervisor int=100,                 -- Default value=100
    @correo varchar(50)='my Default Value', -- Default Value
    @id_area int
    as
    begin

INSERT INTO [dbo].[empleados]
           ([id_emp]
           ,[nom_emp]
           ,[lnom_emp]
           ,[l2nom_emp]
           ,[id_type]
           ,[id_supervisor]
           ,[correo]
           ,[id_area])
     VALUES
           (@id_emp,
           @nom_emp,
           @lnom_emp,
           @l2nom_emp,
           @id_type,
           @id_supervisor,
           @correo,
           @id_area)
return 
end
```

So, you can call the procedure like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[altaemp]
    @id_emp = yourValue,
    @nom_emp = yourValue,
    @lnom_emp = yourValue,
    @l2nom_emp = yourValue,
    @id_type = yourValue,
    @id_supervisor = null,         -- Specify Null or remove parameter
    @correo = null,                -- Specify Null or remove parameter
    @id_area = yourValue
```